# What is '<%%' in ERB in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have bean seen code of scaffold in rails. I found

```
<%% breadcrumb_add "<%= plural_table_name.capitalize %>", <%= plural_table_name %>_path %>
<%%= render 'form' %>
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3fcc0ca99107fa57110421b392f5854555f17fe2/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/_form.html.erb

What is **`<%%`**  and how to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%%` in Erb produces a literal `<%` in the output. You can use it if you want the *output* of your template to also be Erb, which is what is happening in the Rails example you link to.

In your code, the output will be something like (if the variable `plural_table_name` is `things`):

```
<% breadcrumb_add "Things", thing_path %>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

which itself is Erb.